# Kafka Streams - Json

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm thinking to do the following.

1. Topic1 has JSON data

   Ex: **`{"name":"alice","userid":82,"emailid":"abc@xx.com"}`**
2. Topic 2 has JSON data

   Ex: **`{"address":"xxxx","userid":82,"phone":"xxxx"}`**

Considering there is no key defined, meaning its null on both the topics.

I would like to fetch the data and join them based on userid - I understand the code for string data.

```
GlobalKTable<String, String> usersGlobalTable = builder.globalTable("user-table");

// we get a stream of user purchases
KStream<String, String> userPurchases = builder.stream("user-purchases");

// we want to enrich that stream
KStream<String, String> userPurchasesEnrichedJoin =
        userPurchases.join(usersGlobalTable,
                (key, value) -> key, /* map from the (key, value) of this stream to the key of the GlobalKTable */
                (userPurchase1, userInfo1) -> "Purchase=" + userPurchase1 + ",UserInfo=[" + userInfo1 + "]"
        );

userPurchasesEnrichedJoin.to("user-purchases-enriched-inner-join");
```

Can someone help with the code snippet for JSON or any guidance, please.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What issues are you having with parsing the value into a json object using your favorite JSON library?

Comment: Please edit your question to include formatted code and your stream properties

Comment: If you want to load data into a global-KTable for joining it must have a valid key. Hence, you will first need to extract the join-attribute from JSON, set is a record key, write the result into a topic, and use this result topic as input topic for you GlobalKTable.

Comment: Hi,
The flow is working fine for me after following the below steps.
1. Create POJO class for topic1, topic2 related JSON data
2 Extract the value and set it as a key through flatmap.
3. Perform join operation (Streams/KTable) based on the key.